# Existence of countable model of $T$ isomorphic to it's own proper substructure

Tags: model-theory

Exercise goes as follows:

Assume $T$ is $\mathcal{L}$-theory, where $|\mathcal{L}|$ is finite and it has a model $\mathcal{M}$ which is isomorphic to it's own proper substructure. Show that $T$ has a countable model isomorphic to it's own proper substructure.

To begin with, I'm confused of how it is possible that some model $\mathcal{M}$ has a proper substructure $\mathcal{N}$ such that there is isomorphic $\mathcal{L}$-embedding $\eta: N \to M$. Since $\eta$ is isomorphic, how it is possible that $\mathcal{N}$ is **proper** substructure? I think proper would mean $N \subsetneq M$.

I would appreciate any help of explaining it.

EDIT: Now I understand the text of the exercise fully, but how can I show it is true for any such $T$? I would appreciate any hints on how can I prove this.

EDIT2: So here is my attempt to prove it:

Let $T$ be a theory in a finite language $\mathcal{L}$ and let  $\mathcal{L}$-structures $\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{N}$ be such that $\mathcal{M} \models T$, $\mathcal{N} \subsetneq \mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N} \cong \mathcal{M}$.
Let $\mathcal{L}^* = \mathcal{L}\cup \{f\}$, where $f$ a new unary function symbol and let $\varphi = \varphi_1 \land \varphi_2 \land \varphi_3$, where
$$ \varphi_1 \text{ is } \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (f(v_1) = f(v_2) \Rightarrow v_1 = v_2) \quad \text{(}f\text{ is an injection)} $$
$$ \varphi_2 \text{ is } \forall v_2 \exists v_1 (f(v_1) = v_2) \quad \text{(}f\text{ is onto)} $$
$$ \varphi_3 \text{ is } \exists v_3 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 (f(v_1) = v_2 \Rightarrow \neg(v_1 = v_3)) \quad \text{(image of }f\text{ is not equal to its domain)} $$
and
$$ T^* = T \cup \{ \varphi \} $$
Let $\eta: \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{N}$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-isomorphism. If we let $f^{\mathcal{M}}(a) = \eta(a)$, then clearly $\mathcal{M} \models T^*$ as an $\mathcal{L}^*$-structure. Now, by Lowenheim–Skolem theorem, there exist countable elementary $\mathcal{L}^*$-substructure $\mathcal{S} \preceq \mathcal{M}$. Therefore, by the construction of $T^*$, $f^{\mathcal{S}}: S \to f^{\mathcal{S}}[S]$ is an isomorphism. Moreover, by $\varphi_3$, $f^{\mathcal{S}}[S] \neq S$, so $f^{\mathcal{S}}$ defines a proper isomorphic $\mathcal{L}^*$-substructure of $\mathcal{S}$. Finally, since $\mathcal{S} \models T^*$, then $\mathcal{S} \models T$, so $\mathcal{S}$ is a countable model of $T$ isomorphic to its own proper substructure.

Comment: hi chandz. consider for example the theory $T$ of infinite sets in the empty language $\mathcal{L}_{\varnothing}=\varnothing$. let $N\subsetneq M$ be any sets of the same cardinality. (eg take $N=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Q}$.) then $N$ and $M$ are both models of $T$, and any bijection $\eta:N\to M$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{L}_{\varnothing}$-structures. does that example help?

Comment: Lots of structures are isomorphic to proper substructures of themselves, in the same way that lots of *sets* are *in bijection with* proper sub*sets* of themselves. In fact, in the empty language, "structure" amounts exactly to "set" and "isomorphism" reduces to just "bijection," so this gives an example (as Atticus Stonestrom says above).

Comment: if that example feels too trivial, let $\mathcal{L}_{<}=\{<\}$ be a language with a single binary relation $<$. make $M=\mathbb{N}$ and $N=2\mathbb{N}\subsetneq M$ into $\mathcal{L}_{<}$-structures in the natural way. can you show that the map $\eta:M\to N$ taking $n$ to $2n$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Oh damn, yes, it helps, it is obvious, I had some brain fog I think

Comment: no worries! :) now that that is clear, do you want to try the exercise yourself, or would you still like a solution?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom I'd like some hints of how can I prove this, which theorems to use and how to approach it.

Comment: Improved hint: show that is consistent to extend the theory with a new function symbol $f(x)$ and axioms asserting that $f(x)$ is an isomorphism of the universe with a proper substructure.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Add an extra unary function symbol $f$ and choose an $L\cup \{f\}$ theory whose models (as $L$-structures) are exactly the $M\models T$ such $f$ is an isomorphism between $M$ and $f[M]\neq M$, and notice that by hypothesis, this theory is consistent. Then apply Lowenheim-Skolem.

Comment: I wrote a proof of it, could you take a look and say if it is correct? I'm actually not sure if it is correct.

Comment: @chandx: Two things: the way you wrote the axioms, it looks like $f$ is a binary relation symbol (which you use to represent the graph of a function). That is okay, but if you actually use an unary function instead, it's a bit less cumbersome to write. Secondly and more importantly, you did not write any axioms saying that $f$ actually is an isomorphism, only that it is an injection and not a surjection. That is definitely not enough.

Comment: Of course, axioms were bad, but I think now they are good, is it right?

Comment: @chandx: Unfortunately, no. You have not addressed the most important part of my comment: the $f$ you describe is not an isomorphism, only an injection. Nowhere in your axioms do you refer to the other symbols of $L$.